# Hibernate: childEntity null id on merge parentEntity

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

I've the code:

```
modifiedParentEntity.addChild(newChildEntity);
session.merge(modifiedParentEntity);
newChildEntity.getId(); // == 0!!!
```

Where parent entity has a collection of child entities with `CascadeType.ALL`:

```
@Entity
public class ParentEntity {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_entity_id")
    private List<ChildEntity> childEntities;
}
```

***Question:***

1. Why after `session.merge(modifiedParentEntity)` chidEntity has `0` id?
2. How to save both `modifiedParentEntity` and `chidEntity` in a way that Hibernate will set id to `chidEntity`?

***P.S.***:

I use postgres and sequences to generate entities' ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[merge](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge%28java.lang.Object%29) operation does not make the passed entity managed, but rather returns another instance that is managed

so you need to get the id from managed instance as follows

```
modifiedParentEntity.addChild(newChildEntity);
ModifiedParentEntity modifiedParentManaged= session.merge(modifiedParentEntity);
session.flush()
```

Then get the child entity from `modifiedParentManaged` and then get its id.

Comment: I use manual flush mode, so I can't use `flush` at the middle of my handle-method. I can solve this problem by adding `session.save(newChildEntity)` before merging parent entity.

Comment: Ok. In your case it is better to make the child managed before merging the parent.In the above style if you are not using flush then the children will be set with id only after transaction is complete.